# Can I locate my iPhone 4 using Find my iPhone if the setting is disabled on the device?

Tags: iphone, ios, find-my-iphone

My iPhone is lost.
I tried using Find my iPhone but I realised I turned off the setting that is required for this. What can I do?

Comment: The majority of people walking on this Earth is still honest. So call your number and see is someone will pick up. You need to know if they find your phone mostly they wont know whose phone is it, and how to reach you.

Answer (score 1):

No, Find my iPhone requires that the relevant service (namely iCloud → Find my iPhone) is enabled so that the device can be tracked and communicated with. If this service is disabled on the device, the device can't be tracked by you using iCloud.